# Richtextbox data to Datagridview Cell.- VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I was wondering how do you pass a value of BLOB to a datagridview cell.

I passed the richtextbox content to the database using

```
Dim questionContent as Byte() 
questionContent = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RichTextBox1.Rtf)
```

And for retrieving I used

```
RichTextBox2.Rtf = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(blobFromDatabase)
```

The problem is, when I try to query for the columns an error appears when trying to load the Blob datatype from the database and a red x just appears in the cell. I would like to know how the cell can get RTF data. Note that I am also getting both Images and Formatted Text inside the cell.

Comment: Please take the time to read what **RTF** format is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Comment: I'm sorry but does that mean it's not possible

Comment: Use `nvarchar(max)` instead of `blob`. Write/read `richTextBox.Rtf` property directly to/from this column.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP PhpMyAdmin. What would be the equivalent?